# Converting 24hour time format to 12hour time?

Tags: java, android

```
String s = "12:18:00";
DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date d = f1.parse(s);
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
f2.format(d).toLowerCase(); // "12:18am"
```

Tried the above however it returns 11:18pm?

Comment: This is a Java documentation bug, Try `HH` and `k`

Comment: It gives me "12:18am", but I tried on java hotspot JRE.

Comment: pentium hh and k at where? mind specifying. thanks

Comment: My android also gives me "12:18AM". What version of android do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
final String time = "12:18:00";

try {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
    final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println(dateObj);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(dateObj));
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907968/how-to-convert-24-hr-format-time-in-to-12-hr-format).

Comment: wow did you even try that? i tried on my phone and it gives same result. 11:48

Comment: I've tested his code on 3 different phones and it works fine using various times.

Comment: Try reading this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which describes the date formats. you may be looking for "h" where he has "K" above since K = 0-12 where as h = 1-12. Replace "K:mm" with "h:mma" to get 12:18pm However, the code above is correct and should be marked as such. Your problem may lie with the initial simple date format initialization. You have "hh:mm:ss" which is not the format you are providing to be parsed. Use "H:mm" as above.

Comment: are you sure u tested on 3 different phone with the same exact code and time time being

final String time = "12:18:00";