# How to convert 12hr to 24hr using java

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi in my `PostgreSQL` in using time without time zone to save a specific time `(19:36:17.376)`, and in my web application in using jQuery  date picket for picking a time from client side for search by time in the format`(12:30 PM)`.
How to convert the time `12:30 PM`to this format`(19:36:17.376)`.

i am using hibernate for searching.
searching java code

```
String queryString = "from TicketBooking  t where t.isSale='true' ";    queryString = queryString
                    + " and t.time BETWEEN :stTime AND :edTime";  SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
             SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-mm-dd hh:mm a");
               Date date1 = parseFormat.parse(fromTime);
               Date date2 = parseFormat.parse(toTime);
               System.out.println( displayFormat.format(date1)+"------------------"+displayFormat.format(date2));
                        query.setParameter("stTime", displayFormat.format(date1));          query.setParameter("edTime", displayFormat.format(date2));
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")` to convert the `String` to a `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS")` to convert the `Date` to a `String`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907968/how-to-convert-24-hr-format-time-in-to-12-hr-format

Comment: getting below exception  
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - HHH000106: For
cing container resource cleanup on transaction completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `12:30 PM` to `Date`...

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date date = inFormat.parse("12:30 PM");
```

Convert `Date` to `19:36:17.376` like format...

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String out = outFormat.format(date);
```

Now personally, I'd leave the `Date` as it is and wrap it within a `java.sql.Date` and pass that to the database for it to handle...

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

And not worry about trying to format the `Date` to a `String`, but that's me

Have a look at [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a SimpleDateFormat object to convert the time formats.

```
final String time = "23:15";

try {

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");

    final Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);

    System.out.println(dateObj);

    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(dateObj));


} catch (final ParseException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();


}
```

here the download link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html