# Time is Automatically Converted

Tags: java, jsp

In the JSP, there is a timepicker. I use request.getParameter("StartTime") to get the value. But the time automatically converts to 24-hour format.

In JSP File:

`<input type="time" name="StartTime"> //06:00 PM`

Java File:

`String startTime = request.getParameter("StartTime"); //18:00`

I also try to convert it using SimpleDateFormat but it just skips.

Is there other ways to get the value of time input type.

Comment: Use ``java.text.SimpleDateFormat``

Comment: @rev_dihazum I also tried it but it just skips.

Comment: could see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907968/how-to-convert-24-hr-format-time-in-to-12-hr-format