# How to change 12 Hours to 24 Hours using Scala

Tags: scala, simpledateformat

I want 12 Hours Time format convert into 24 Hours time format, Here I attached my code and I checked this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907968/how-to-convert-24-hr-format-time-in-to-12-hr-format),[link2](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Timein12hourformat.htm) but it return as same time format.

Code

```
val inTime = "12:15 PM"
val newTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
val timeWithDateFormat = newTimeFormat.parse(inTime)
val outputTime = newTimeFormat.format(timeWithDateFormat)
println("Output===========>",outputTime)
```

Output is:

```
(Output===========>,12:15 PM)
```

How can I resolved it.

Comment: As you want your output to be in adifferent format thab your input, when you are creating the `outputTime` String, use a different `DateTimeFormat`, `val outputDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")`. Also please learn to read the documentation, as it is clearly explained here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want your output to be in a different format than your input, you will need to use a different formatters for input and output.

Also... `12:15 PM` of 12-hour-format is `12:15` of 24-hour-format. So may be you should use a different time for this example (lets use `03:15 PM` or `15:15`),

```
val inTime = "03:15 PM"

val inputTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")

val timeWithDateFormat = inputTimeFormat.parse(inTime)

val outputTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")

val outputTime = outputTimeFormat.format(timeWithDateFormat)

println("Output===========>", outputTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create new `SimpleDateFormat` and use it to format your date;

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
```

For details you can check documentation;

[Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)