# Getting different values for Timestamp.valueOf

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to get the timestamp value for 2018-09-04 13:43:32.922000 by doing 
`Timestamp.valueOf("2018-09-04 13:43:32.922000")`

my expected output is 2018-09-04 13:43:32.922

but I am getting 2018-09-04 01:13:32.922

It might be due to different timezone because my team in India got the exact result but I am here in California gets the different result.
Suggest the changes that can solve this problem.

Comment: Don't use `Timestamp.valueOf`. Use `DateTimeFormatter` it allow to specify format and timezone of your data.

Comment: The difference being 12 hours 30 minutes and India being involved (at offset +05:30) makes it very likely that this is indeed a time zone issue. The outdated `Timestamp` class is no friend of time zones.

Comment: Without code we can’t answer. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    Instant
    .parse( 
        "2018-09-04 13:43:32.922000"
        .replace( " " , "T" )
        .concat( "Z" )  
    ) 
    .atZone(
        ZoneOffset.UTC
    )
)
```

## java.time

> Suggest the changes that can solve this problem.

**Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`.**

Among the many flaws of that class is that the [method you call is not documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) to explain its behavior while parsing. It appears your JVM’s current default time zone is being silently applied with some adjustment. But the issue is moot.

That terribly-designed class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310, specifically `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime`.

Change your input string to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2018-09-04 13:43:32.922000".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Was your input intended to represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), an offset of zero? If so, append a `Z` (pronounced Zulu).

```
String input = "2018-09-04 13:43:32.922000".replace( " " , "T" ).concat( "Z" ) ;
```

The `Instant` class represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) may optionally accept a `Instant` object.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( instant ) ;
```

If your JDBC driver does not support `Instant`, use `OffsetDateTime`. Support is required in JDBC 4.2 and later.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ; 
myPreparedStatement.setObject( odt ) ;
```

Notice how your JVM’s current default time zone at runtime is irrelevant, with no impact on the code above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: worked for me flawlessly. did "Timestamp.from(Instant.parse("2018-09-04T08:13:32.922000Z"))"

Answer (score -3):

I do not think the issue is due to different time zones. Its just that the output that you are getting is in 24 hour format and that needs to be converted to 12 hour format. Please refer [How to convert 24 hr format time in to 12 hr Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907968/how-to-convert-24-hr-format-time-in-to-12-hr-format) to convert the time to 12 hour format.

Comment: is it possible that in one machine i am getting it in 24 hr format and in another one, I get in12 hr format?  Also if you see, the difference is 12hrs 30 mins. So, i believe that's not the case otherwise there will be 12 hrs of difference.

Comment: `Timestamp.toString` always prints in 24 hour format.