# Convert a string (H:mm) to (h:mm a) in recycler view adapter

Tags: android

I want to convert the "H:mm" value of time that i am getting from my Firestore database to "h:mm a" but i am not able to, getting "Unparseable date" and sometimes just plain it's not working.

```
    val strTime = studentAttendanceList[position].Time.toString() //time from firebase store in "H:mm" format
    val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm")
    val date = dateFormat.parse(strTime)
    val f2 = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a")
    f2.format(date).lowercase()
```

I want to get this time in

```
h:mm a
```

For example -

```
16:00 to 4:00 pm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.time.LocalTime` might be the answer to your problems.

1. If you have your time represented as a string use this:
   `val result = LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));`
2. If you have your data as a date time use this where localTimeInstance is your time represented as a LocalTim:
   `val result = localTimeInstance.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));`

Comment: It worked, TY but i wanted something that can work on API 23 and up. This Required API 26 and up, is there a way i can make this work on API 23?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190056/13533028 This should work on any api level. Also don't forget to accept the answer so that it helps other people as well. Welcome to StackOverflow .:)